# Encountered the symbol "WHILE" when expecting one of the following: . ( * @ % & - + / at loop mod remainder rem

Tags: oracle, plsql, cursor

Hi i'm a begginer in pl/sql under oracle. i'tried to write this pl/SQL programm but i had this error:

> Encountered the symbol "WHILE" when expecting one of the following: . ( * @ % & - + / at loop mod remainder rem ..'

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON

DECLARE

CURSOR EMP_CURSOR IS SELECT EMPLOYEE_NAME, SALARY, DATE_HIRE FROM EMPLOYEES WHERE DEPARTMENT_ID=1;

BEGIN

FOR EMP_REC IN EMP_CURSOR
WHILE EMP_REC%FOUND

    LOOP
        IF EMP_REC.SALARY > 10000  AND   EMP_REC.DATE_HIRE< DATE '2000-01-01'
        THEN 
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (EMP_REC.EMPLOYEE_NAME ||  ' earns ' || EMP_REC.SALARY ||  'and joined the organization                on ' || EMP_REC.DATE_HIRE); 
        END IF;
    END LOOP;
END LOOP;
END;
/ 
SET SERVEROUTPUT OFF
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DECLARE

    CURSOR EMP_CURSOR IS SELECT EMPLOYEE_NAME, SALARY, DATE_HIRE FROM EMPLOYEES WHERE DEPARTMENT_ID=1;

BEGIN

FOR EMP_REC IN EMP_CURSOR

    LOOP
        IF EMP_REC.SALARY > 10000  AND   EMP_REC.DATE_HIRE< DATE '2000-01-01'
        THEN 
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (EMP_REC.EMPLOYEE_NAME ||  ' earns ' || EMP_REC.SALARY ||  'and joined the organization                on ' || EMP_REC.DATE_HIRE); 
        END IF;
    END LOOP;

END;
```

Comment: thank you for your response, i tried this cod before it work's but i don't understand why the  line WHILE EMP_REC%FOUND doesn't work with the for loop and works when i used a FETCH with the cursor??

Comment: The cursor for loop does an implicit open, fetch and close. There is no use to use EMP_REC%FOUND here. This would be syntactic correct but would result in a infinite loop as you do not fetch in the inner statement: `BEGIN

    FOR EMP_REC IN EMP_CURSOR
    LOOP

        WHILE EMP_REC%FOUND LOOP
        
            -- Do something forever
            NULL; 
            
        END LOOP;
        
    END LOOP;
    
END;` (Sorry, I can not figure out how to format this well in a comment...)

Comment: Hi,i stay have this error :PLS-00324: cursor attribute may not be applied to non-cursor 'EMP_REC' with the for loop

Comment: Oh, sorry: `EMP_CURSOR%FOUND`

Comment: Hi,I tried with EMP_CURSOR%FOUND it doesn't work too